# Converting MS Word API to Aspose Word API

Tags: excel, aspose, aspose-cells, vba

Could you please provide code for converting the following VB code using MS Word to VB.NET using Aspose Word?

```
 Dim os AS Excel.Worksheet
 oS.Range("A55", "S55").Select()
 oS.Application.Selection.Copy()
 oS.Application.Selection.Insert(Shift:=Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
```

thans all and Best wishies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are interested in a code for Aspose.Cells API rather than Aspose.Words API as you are manipulating Excel files.

Well, as per your shared code, you are getting a range of cells, copying the cells at the same selected location with "Shift Cells Down" option. You can transform this to Aspose.Cells code as below:

```
'Open the Source Excel file
Dim workbook As New Workbook("C:\Test_File.xlsx")

'get cells collection of first worksheet
Dim cells As Cells = workbook.Worksheets(0).Cells


'get the source range to copy
Dim sourceRange As Range = cells.CreateRange("A55:S55")

'Insert the range below the source range 
Dim ca As CellArea = CellArea.CreateCellArea("A56", "S56")
cells.InsertRange(ca, ShiftType.Down)

' Move Source Range one Row down as Copy process has Shift Cells Down option selected
' this is only required if you have a named range and want it shifted as in Excel   
sourceRange.MoveTo(55, 0)

'create destination range
Dim destinationRange As Range = cells.CreateRange("A55:S55")

'Copy the source range data to desitnation range (newly inserted range)
destinationRange.Copy(sourceRange)

'save the resultant file
workbook.Save("C:\Test_Out.xlsx")
```

Hopefully, the above code will help you in your implementation.